# Construct SQL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I wanna do

```
SomeModel.where(blahblah)
```

and if certain param has been set, then I also want to order the selection

```
SomeModel.where(blahblah).order(blahblah)
```

I don't want to have to do

```
if something
   SomeModel.where(blahblah)
else
   SomeModel.where(blahblah).order(blahblah)
end
```

because it's repetitive.

Is there some way that allows me to construct a SQL statement with conditionals, and then execute it later? Something similar to constructing a SQL string through concatenation and then executing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the point of ARel:

```
x = SomeModel.where(blahblah)
x = x.order(blah) if something
```

Comment: You're using Rails. You're already doing .where and .order. That's all ARel. ActiveRecord::Relation. In other words, you don't need to add another gem, you already have the gem you need for this.